# How to partial transform in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have done XSLT transformation on the XML and now would like to apply XSLT to alter some of the content.

How to wrap all the **tr** element in **table** element? I am was using XSLT 1.0 in C#.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<div class="group">
  <div class="group-header">A</div>
  <div class="group-body">
    <div class="group">
      <div class="group-header">B</div>
      <div class="group-body">
        <div class="group">
          <div class="group-header">C</div>
          <div class="group-body">
            <tr>C1</tr>
            <tr>C2</tr>
            <tr>C3</tr>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <div class="group-header">D</div>
          <div class="group-body">
            <tr>D1</tr>
            <tr>D2</tr>
            <tr>D3</tr>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Expected Result:

[image]

Comment: Well, what is the task? To wrap all adjacent `tr` elements into a `table` element? Which version of XSLT, which XSLT processor do you use/can you use?

Comment: Hi @Martin, sorry for missing info

Comment: Do you know that those `div class="group-body"` elements do always contain only `tr` elements that need to be wrapped by a `table` parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply start with the identity transformation template and then add a template for elements containing `tr` children to wrap them in a `table`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(self::table) and tr]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
          <table>
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </table>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKwV

Comment: Hi Martin, need some minor help, how about in this scenario? https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTzX/8 additional conditions needed? Sorry for inconveniences

Comment: Hi Martin, I have solved it, will ask another for the perfect solution for XSLT, because currently, I have used 2 templates to complete the conversion process. By the way, thanks and happy weekend !